# PHP Carbon, are two dates within another two dates

Tags: php, php-carbon

I am using PHP and Carbon and would like to check if two dates fall between another two dates.

As an example, say I have:

```
$eventStart = '2023-04-01';
$eventEnd = '2023-09-14';

$rangeStart = '2023-07-01';
$rangeEnd = '2023-07-31';
```

The 'event' which runs from 1st April until 14th September, does fall within the 'range' I want to check, which starts on 1st July up to 31st July.

So given any two start and end 'event' dates, how can I check that they fall within another two start and end 'range' dates?

Comment: _"The 'event' which runs from 1st April until 14th September, does fall within the 'range' I want to check, which starts on 1st July up to 31st July."_ - so actually, it is exactly the other way around then - your range falls completely between the event start and end dates.

Comment: It is unclear here whether you are looking only for a full overlap, or if you also want to consider partial ones. (Say, event starts in Januar and goes until April, range starts in Februar and goes into June - that also a match, or not?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CarbonPeriod::contains()`

> Return true if the given date is between start and end.

```php
$eventStart = '2023-04-01';
$eventEnd = '2023-09-14';

$rangeStart = '2023-07-01';
$rangeEnd = '2023-07-31';

$eventPeriod = CarbonPeriod::create($eventStart, $eventEnd);
$rangePeriod = CarbonPeriod::create($rangeStart, $rangeEnd);

$eventPeriod->contains($rangePeriod);
```

Comment: Wait, `contains()` takes a date as parameter (as said in the doc) so it only tests that $rangeStart is between $eventStart and $eventEnd. It does not check the overlap (if rangeStart is before the eventPeriod, but rangeEnd is in (or after) for instance.

Comment: Another comments, periods can overlap without the start/end of the event falling in the range, for instance the event can start before the range start and end after the range end. (So overlaps() method basically also checks the reciprocal fall of the range start/end in the event.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CarbonPeriod::overlaps()`

> Returns true if the current period overlaps the given one (if 1 parameter passed) or the period between 2 dates (if 2 parameters passed).

```php
$eventStart = '2023-04-01';
$eventEnd = '2023-09-14';

$rangeStart = '2023-07-01';
$rangeEnd = '2023-07-31';

$eventPeriod = CarbonPeriod::create($eventStart, $eventEnd);
$rangePeriod = CarbonPeriod::create($rangeStart, $rangeEnd);

$eventPeriod->overlaps($rangePeriod);
```